# Visual Studio 2010 deployment error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I tried to follow the instructions from the site http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3008/building-and-deploying-a-database/
to start working with visual studio. I succeeded testing the connection with the server. I chose the server name - the name of the computer +"\sqlexpress" and the Target database name - the name of the database i was building(the same as in the site's instructions).

Now, when i click Build, in the menu bar, then build DemoDB, the program compiles properly. But when i choose Deploy DemoDB, i get the following error, which i do not understand:

```
 Inserting Seed Data for FootBallClub Table
C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DemoDB\DemoDB\sql\debug\DemoDB.sql(70,0): Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Invalid object name 'dbo.FootBallClub'.
    An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
   Done executing task "SqlDeployTask" -- FAILED.
  Done building target "DspDeploy" in project "DemoDB.dbproj" -- FAILED.
 Done executing task "CallTarget" -- FAILED.
Done building target "DBDeploy" in project "DemoDB.dbproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "DemoDB.dbproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am i supposed to do? What other setting information should i tell you in order to help me with this?

Comment: Provide the section of DemoDB.sql that is failing.

Comment: The error message seems pretty straight forward.  When the DemoDB.sql script is run, sql is reporting there is no object 'dbo.FootBallClub'.

Comment: The Table FootBallClub doesn't exist in the database

Answer (score 0):

I verified the table DemoDB.sql and i found some errors. But those errors are in the code that was generated by visual studio, not in the code i wrote. I just followed some steps from a site to create this data base. i do not know what else i have to modify. As i said before, i am new with this pragramming languages.

This is the automatic generated code in DemoDB.sql:

```
/*
Deployment script for DemoDB
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "DemoDB"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\"

GO
USE [master]

GO
:on error exit
GO
IF (DB_ID(N'$(DatabaseName)') IS NOT NULL
    AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'$(DatabaseName)','Status') <> N'ONLINE')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'The state of the target database, %s, is not set to ONLINE. To deploy to this database, its state must be set to ONLINE.', 16, 127,N'$(DatabaseName)') WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases] WHERE [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'You cannot deploy this update script to target JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS. The database for which this script was built, DemoDB, does not exist on this server.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

GO

IF (@@servername != 'JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'The server name in the build script %s does not match the name of the target server %s. Verify whether your database project settings are correct and whether your build script is up to date.', 16, 127,N'JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS',@@servername) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

GO

IF CAST(DATABASEPROPERTY(N'$(DatabaseName)','IsReadOnly') as bit) = 1
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'You cannot deploy this update script because the database for which it was built, %s , is set to READ_ONLY.', 16, 127, N'$(DatabaseName)') WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END

GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)]

GO
/*
 Pre-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be executed before the build script.   
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the pre-deployment script.          
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the pre-deployment script.        
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

GO
/*
Post-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be appended to the build script.       
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the post-deployment script.         
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the post-deployment script.       
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

And this is my completion, which is correct, apparently:

```
print 'Inserting Seed Data for FootBallClub Table'

insert dbo.FootBallClub select 1, 'Callingmen', 'London'
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.FootBallClub where FootBallClubID=1)

insert dbo.FootBallClub select 2, 'Explorers', 'Barcelona'
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.FootBallClub where FootBallClubID=2)

insert dbo.FootBallClub select 3, 'Autobahns', 'Munich'
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.FootBallClub where FootBallClubID=3)
```